# How can i continue the user to the requested page after authenticated?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering how can i continue the user requested page after authenticated with `laravel 5.2`? Do i need to set a session or laravel has something to do this?

Example: I am not registered yet. I am looking for a product. I click `"Order Now"` button. Then i go to `login/register` page. After getting authenticated i go to the order page with the product that i want to order.

Sorry for my newbie question. May i can get some help on how to make this process right. Or maybe i get some references for this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the intended URL method in Laravel.

Eg:

```
public function authenticate()
{
   if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $email, 'password'=>$password])
  {
      return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
   }
}
```

In the above example, the user will be redirected to the 'dashboard' after login if there's no intended URL. Else, he will be redirected to the last page after login.

Intended url is the page from which the user is being redirected to login.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Wow coll. its works.. thank you.. But it doesnt work if i login via facebook. Whats is your solution for this?

Comment: Can you ask it as a separate question with ur code?

Comment: Yes, but i just fix it..i just add this intended to my handleProviderCallback method. :D